# Failing to install Github package, "had non-zero exit status" error

Tags: r, github

I have been unsuccessful at installing the package 'HonestDiD' from Github. It says that the package in question 'had non-zero exit status.' I followed the instructions given [here](https://rdrr.io/github/asheshrambachan/HonestDiD/f/doc/HonestDiD_Example.Rmd). Any idea how to solve this issue? Here is the code/full error message.

```
    devtools::install_github("asheshrambachan/HonestDiD")
    Downloading GitHub repo asheshrambachan/HonestDiD@HEAD
    These packages have more recent versions available.
    It is recommended to update all of them.
    Which would you like to update?
    
     1: All                                      
     2: CRAN packages only                       
     3: None                                     
    
    Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:3
    √  checking for file 'C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkZzlr8\remotes43401e3a797\asheshrambachan-HonestDiD-1723b17/DESCRIPTION' ...
    -  preparing 'HonestDiD': (601ms)
    √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
    -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
    -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
    -  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
    -  building 'HonestDiD_0.1.0.tar.gz'
       
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/louis/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    * installing *source* package 'HonestDiD' ...
    ** using staged installation
    ** R

** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'CVXR' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'HonestDiD'
* removing 'C:/Users/louis/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/HonestDiD'
Error: Failed to install 'HonestDiD' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/.../HonestDiD_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: This seems similar to [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/434). See if the solution in the first post helps

Comment: When it asked "Which would you like to update?" what did you choose? Its usually safest to choose 3-None.

Comment: You can also try running `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")` before installing.

Comment: I chose 3/none. still did not work. Using:Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")

as suggested by MrFlick worked. Thanks!